# cakephp - naming tables and using cake bake

Tags: cakephp

I'm having some weird behaviour from the cake console and I can't figure out what could possibly be wrong!

I've used the cake bake console before and not had any problems so hopefully it's not something glaringly stupid.

I have the tables: users, images and folders.

Folders and images both have user_id's

When I run the cake bake all on the folders table it bakes the controller and model but there's errors baking the views. I figured perhaps you can't call a table folders because of conventions or whatever so I renamed it 'archives'.

Now when I run the console and cd to myApp/app and cake bake all I get the model:
1 archife
2..

archife??

My table is most definitely called archives. I've changed the name a bunch of times to other names to check and it only seems to be on the particular word archives which it turns into archife. I've checked other words with 'v' in it but they're fine.

So.. my questions are twofold. Can we not use the table name folders because there's some problem with it? It's the only name I've come across apart from pages which you can't use as a table name because it clashes.

And, why does cake bake the table archives to the model archife?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Model names should be unique...

As a general rule, don't use names for your tables that would result in a model class name that equals an existing class name, `Folder` for example is a utility class shipping with CakePHP, and this will cause problems with autoloading as you've experienced.

This is a problem that should/will be fixed with CakePHP 3, where namespaces are being used.

### ...and singular

`archives` being turned into `archife` sounds like it could be an [**`Inflector`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html) bug/conflict, try

```
debug(Inflector::singularize('archives'));
```

It's working fine for me using CakePHP 2.5.1, ie it returns `archive` as expected, so I'd suggest to upgrade your CakePHP version, and report it as a bug in case it's happening with a recent version.