# Cakephp Call to undefined method Directory::find() after changing the classname

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-2.4

I'm using Cakephp 2.4.

I named one of my table folders (which was a logic name) but I just discover that was a reserved word in cake ... So I tried to change folders to directories (in model/controller/views) but i still get the error

> Call to undefined method Directory::find()

My model is now

> Directory.php

:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Directory Model
 *
 * @property Installation $Installation
 */
class Directory extends AppModel {

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'name';
    public $useTable = 'directories';

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Installation' => array(
            'className' => 'Installation',
            'foreignKey' => 'installation_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

I also change **hasMany** array in my Installation model

My controller

> DirectoriesController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Directories Controller
 *
 * @property Directory $Directory
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 */
class DirectoriesController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator');
}
```

Can someone tell me where I may have missed something ?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: `Directory` is a PHP built in class: **http://php.net/Directory** You'll have to try another name and make sure it doesn't match any existing class. **http://stackoverflow.com/a/23846641/1392379**

Comment: Out of the frying pan and into the fire, huh... @ndm yours is the correct anwser :) Post it as such, hopefully with a link to reserved words in php and in cakephp, to use it as default answer for this type of errors (there's another one going around right now in the unanswered queue).

Comment: @ndm, as Nunser say, you're right ! Thank you for help :)