# Error create cakephp model named "Models"

Tags: php, database, cakephp, content-management-system, cakephp-model

I want to use a model named Models in cakephp, 
I got all the values by using find('all') but my join is not working. ie the $belongsTo ;
I copyed this a replication another working model and controller, I just renamed to make another to make a Model controller and Model table.

pls help me!!!

**Model.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Model extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Models';

    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )

    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Medias'    => array('className' => 'Medias', 'foreignKey'  =>  'featured_image'),
    );
}
```

**ModelsController.php**

```
<?php

class ModelsController extends BackendAppController {

    public $helpers     = array('Html', 'Form');
    public $components  = array('Session', 'RequestHandler');

    public function index() {
        $this->actionTitle("Models");
        $this->loadModel('Models');
        $models = $this->Model->find('all');
        var_dump($models);
        $this->set('models', $models);
    }
```

**// var_dump($models);**

```
array(1) {   [0]=>   array(1) {
    ["Model"]=>
    array(12) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "18"
      ["parent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["featured_image"]=>
      string(2) "22"
      ["owner"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["hidden"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["deleted"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["title"]=>
      string(8) "asdasdas"
      ["description"]=>
      string(10) "dasdasdasd"
      ["created"]=>
      string(19) "2014-07-19 02:47:23"
      ["modified"]=>
      string(19) "2014-07-19 02:48:01"
    }   } }
```

Comment: Not a 100% duplicate, but for the most part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840324/cakephp-naming-tables-and-using-cake-bake/23846641

Answer (score 1):

I think Model of your models table conflict with Model class of Cakephp core class so you should rename your table and associate files (Model,Controller).
you can see cakephp Model class here: http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Model.html

also don't use the global constants and functions names in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html

these names is reserved in cakephp.

Comment: Your answer is a bit fuzzy on details. It's not quite bad enough that I'd recommend it for deletion, but I would expand on it with some examples on how the questioner could fix their problem.